# Assign a list of variables to a specific number of matching variables

Tags: r

I want to take a pre-existing list of names:

```
names <- c('mike', 'barbara', 'judy', 'andy', 'sarah', 'nick', 'dan')
```

Which would be matched to a preset number for each:

```
number <- c('1', '8', '10', '12', '3', '9', '5')
```

As well as a defining group:

```
group <- c('a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'a')
```

I then want to assign each name to the number of records that refreshes every morning.  So, each day there could be 20 records that come in for b, 10 for a, and so on.  So mike would be assigned to 1 a, barbara to 8 a's etc.  I'd like to add a column with the name variable to my future data frame, but not display anything else from the columns above.

My biggest problem is that I really don't know where to start with assigning the amount of names I need to based on the group.  Matching variables from one data frame to another is not a big deal, but I haven't found any examples that match this scenario at all.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand yet, could you please add to your explanation? Is the problem that you want to make a data frame but you don't know how to reflect the records from different dates? What does "but not display anything else from the columns above" mean? If you have `df = data.frame(names = names, number = number, group = group)`, what's your next step that you are stuck on?

Comment: Seems more like `df = data.frame(names, group); repeated_df = df[rep(1:nrow(df), times = as.numeric(number)), ]`... but that doesn't seem like your goal. We need an example of the complete input and desired output. What about the data that refreshes every morning?? Your example data has 3 `b`s, and the `b` numbers add up to 25 (10 + 12 + 3). But you also say *"there could be 20 records that come in for b"*. So, with 25 b names to assign, and only 20 records to assign them to, what is the desired output?

Comment: It seems with `df = data.frame(names = names, number = number, group = group)` the next step is that assignments come in like `assignments <- data.frame(type = c(rep('b', 20), rep('a', 10)))`. I think the question is, how to create a new df1 that shows a name from `names` based on the `number` of `assignments` from each `group` they are supposed to get. Expected outcome would look like `assignments$names <- c(rep('judy',10), rep('andy',10), 'mike', rep('barbara',8), 'dan')`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but Sven's explanation is correct.  It seems like he is pointing me in the right direction, so I will try going down that road.